# I can't access $_POST values through index

Tags: php

I feel like I am going crazy. 
I have submitted the following POST request containing these inputs:

```
...
<textarea type='text' name='description["add"]></textarea>
<textarea type='text' name='description["modify"]></textarea>
<textarea type='text' name='description["delete"]></textarea>
...
```

When I print them out using `print_f($_POST)`, this is the output:

```
[description] => Array
        (
            ["add"] => blah blah blah
            ["modify"] => bleh bleh bleh
            ["delete"] => bloh bloh bloh
        )
```

I want to access the text in `["add"]`. I try `print_r($_POST['description']['add']` but it keeps returning nothing!

How can I access the deeper levels of the $_POST array? Everything I thought I knew about php is wrong!

I have tried other formats like `$_POST['description']->add` and `$_POST['description'][0]`. Both return nothing.

The only way I thing that I found works is iterating using a foreach.

```
foreach ($_POST['description' as $value) {
     print_r($value);
}
```

What am I missing? Please help!! I'm going insane. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The quotes in the HTML array index here `["add"]` are adding actual quotes to the index in PHP, so you would need `$_POST['description']['"add"']`.

Don't use quotes in the HTML array index `name='description[add]'`, then this works `$_POST['description']['add']`.

Also, make sure to use the closing quote around the name `'description[add]'`.